# Is Tor client, relay server and exit node server the same software package?

Tags: configuration

I wonder if the tor software (e.g. that which is installed via `apt-get install tor` in debian/ubuntu, or from the git repo) is always a package that includes the use of Tor as a Client and also as a Relay and Exit node ?

Background to this question is, that i want to avoid to unintentiolly misconfigure Tor. At the present moment my desire and capability is only that of being a User (i.e. client use) not a Provider (i.e. relay or exitnode).

Answering my question would be easy, for somebody who knows, i.e. it would simply consist of confirming  or rejecting whether a normal package of Tor includes directly all functionality (i.e. also that of relaying and exitnoding) or if there is a "client-only" package.

Answer (score 2):

The Tor software includes everything you need to run a relay, exit node or just a client. To be sure you don't accidentally misconfigure anything, you can use the `ClientOnly` option and set it to 1. That way, tor prevents you from accidentally running a relay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the very same software acting in a different roles/modes. It is also a Directory server and HiddenServices directory sever, and the Bridge too.